# In Word 2016 embedded Excel tables can't be scaled via VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

**Context**

I have a Word with multiple embedded Excel tables. These Excel tables vary in width. I try to adjust the Excel spreadsheet widths with VBA code so that they are optimized for the page width of my Word document.

The Excels have been embedded via Insert > Object > Microsoft Excel Worksheet

**Problems**

1. In the code example, the properties `.ScaleWidth` and `.ScaleHeight` have no effect on the size of the tables in Word.
2. If I change the heights and widths with `.Width` and `.Height` the tables refresh back to their original sizes

**Code Example 1**

```
For Each oShape In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
    If oShape.Type = wdInlineShapeEmbeddedOLEObject Then
        If Left(oShape.OLEFormat.ProgID, 5) = "Excel" Then
            oShape.OLEFormat.Activate
            oShape.OLEFormat.Object.Application.Worksheets(1).Activate
            oShape.ScaleWidth = x ' something calculated
            oShape.ScaleHeight = y ' something calculated 
        End If
   End If
Next oShape
```

Comment: I see you've gotten an answer. FWIW the reason the code in the question probably doesn't work is because you're first activated the object. You might want to test that code without using either of the `Activate` lines.

Comment: This is such a simple answer, will try and might be the solution. I need to activate the shapes currently because I manipulate the tables massively too. But should run through a second loop after they have been deactivated again.

Comment: Or, if it works, put the scaling commands in before the activation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from your post whether the worksheets are embedded (perhaps with external referencing for which you might use code to update) or as linked objects. Your "I use Inline Shapes instead of linked Excels" doesn't exactly make this any clearer. For the resizing, try:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Sctn As Section, iShp As InlineShape, sWdth As Single, sHght As Single
For Each Sctn In ActiveDocument.Sections
  With Sctn
    With .PageSetup
      sWdth = .PageWidth - .LeftMargin - .RightMargin - .Gutter
      sHght = .PageHeight - .TopMargin - .BottomMargin
    End With
    For Each iShp In .Range.InlineShapes
      With iShp
        .LockAspectRatio = True
        If .Width > sWdth Then .Width = sWdth
        If .Height > sHght Then .Height = sHght
      End With
    Next
  End With
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The above macro will scale down and over-size inline shapes to fit the print area.

As for your "In some tables the last columns from Excel are not visible in Word" issue, the solution really depends on whether the worksheets are embedded or linked.

Comment: This works perfectly. I also have smaller tables and adapted `If .Width > sWdth Then .Width = sWdth` to `If .Width <> sWdth Then .Width = sWdth`

Comment: @gco In that case, you could just omit the test and use: .Width = sWdth